# Speed up torch.narrow over multiple dimensions

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch

I want to implement a Machine Learning model that, among other things, should learn coefficient for (Quadratic) spline functions. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B-spline for reference). As a part of the forward operation the spline function is applied on the input.

For the computation value of this function I implemented the algorithm as described here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Boor%27s_algorithm
In the initialization step I need to get values out of a tensor of coefficients according to a tensor of indices.
Since I need a range of Indices I used `torch.narrow` for this problem.
However my runtime is dominated by this computation, so I am searching for ways to speed it up

My current code to measure the runtime looks like this:

```
import torch
import time
import torch.nn.functional as F

num_weights = 31
batch_size = 24
values_size = 45 * 45
coeffs = torch.rand(num_weights)
values = torch.rand(batch_size, values_size)
interval = torch.arange(0, 1.1, 0.1)

#This is just so the snippet below works without error
index_tensor = torch.searchsorted(interval, values, right=True, side="right") + 2*torch.ones(values.size(), dtype=torch.int64)
pd = (2,2)
interval = interval.unsqueeze(0)
interval = F.pad(interval, pd, "replicate")
interval = interval.squeeze()


start = time.time()
coeff_matrix = torch.stack([torch.stack([torch.narrow(coeffs, 0, index_tensor[j][i] - 2, 3) for i in range(values_size)]) for j in range(batch_size)])
print("Time to build coeff_matrix", time.time() - start)
```

On my computer I get a runtime of ~0.5 seconds. Just for reference, the other operations in the evaluation amount to ~0.01 seconds
I tried to calculate the matrix first without `torch.stack()` in the middle, but it was slower.
So my question is, if there is a faster method to compute my
`coeff_matrix`
I thought I could use
`torch.gather(),`
but I am unsure about how to do it.
The coefficients are also parameters in the real application, so it is important to not break the gradient.

Comment: My last intuition seemed to be right, the following snippet did the trick for me: 
`bigger_coeffs = coeffs.unsqueeze(0).unsqueeze(0)
bigger_coeffs = coeffs.expand(batch_size, values_size, -1)
bigger_index_tensor = index_tensor.unsqueeze(-1).expand(index_tensor.shape[0], index_tensor.shape[1], 3)
sub = torch.tensor([2, 1, 0])
index_tensor_res  = bigger_index_tensor - sub[None, None, :]
coeff_matrix_4 = torch.gather(bigger_coeffs, 2, index_tensor_res)`